# How to Request Android NDK Camera Permission from C++ code?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm Writing the app in pure c++ and i have the code to open the camera.
and set-up the AndroidManifest.xml as:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="true" />
```

when running the app for the first time it does not provide the prompt to turn permission on. after the installation i have to do it manually by,
Settings->Apps->"MyApp"->Permissions.

How do I provide the prompt in c++, without introducing java code?
All help is greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have seen this as well.

1. To do it manually you can also do it via command line with `adb shell pm grant com.package.name android.permission.CAMERA`
2. To check if permissions are there `adb shell dumpsys package com.package.name`
3. [This is the series of steps to ask for permissions with Java](https://github.com/justinjoy/native-camera2/commit/fd112c3804737803ed021fc5175c95e3a18c516e)
4. To figure out how to do it without Java, you will need to dig into the AOSP to find how it is [working under the hood](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/search?q=requestPermissions&defs=&refs=&path=&hist=&project=art&project=bionic&project=bootable&project=build&project=cts&project=dalvik&project=developers&project=development&project=device&project=docs&project=external&project=frameworks&project=hardware&project=kernel&project=libcore&project=libnativehelper&project=packages&project=pdk&project=platform_testing&project=prebuilts&project=sdk&project=system&project=test&project=toolchain&project=tools)... which isn't trivial and no examples to be found.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done using JNI calls. See example below for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE (can be easily adapted to camera perms).

Call the function:

```
 check_android_permissions(struct android_app* app)
```

(source below) when the application starts.

Several gotchas:

- android.Manifest.permission is a class nested in android.Manifest,
  hence its JNI name is "android/Manifest$permission".
- I did not manage to
  access ContextCompat (android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat) and
  ActivityCompat (android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat ) from JNI, so
  I used Context (android.content.Context) and Activity
  (android.app.Activity) directly. As a consequence, Android API Level 23 (Marshmallow, May 2015) is needed.
- The constants need to be retrieved in the classes, in particular READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are static strings in android.Manifest.permission, and PERMISSION_GRANTED a static integer in android.content.pm.PackageManager.
- I did not implement how to handle when the user clicks the 'do not ask me again' button, this would require to implement the  onRequestPermissionsResult() callback.

```
/**
 * \brief Gets the internal name for an android permission.
 * \param[in] lJNIEnv a pointer to the JNI environment
 * \param[in] perm_name the name of the permission, e.g.,
 *   "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE".
 * \return a jstring with the internal name of the permission,
 *   to be used with android Java functions 
 *   Context.checkSelfPermission() or Activity.requestPermissions()
 */
jstring android_permission_name(JNIEnv* lJNIEnv, const char* perm_name) {
    // nested class permission in class android.Manifest,
    // hence android 'slash' Manifest 'dollar' permission
    jclass ClassManifestpermission = lJNIEnv->FindClass(
       "android/Manifest$permission"
    );
    jfieldID lid_PERM = lJNIEnv->GetStaticFieldID(
       ClassManifestpermission, perm_name, "Ljava/lang/String;"
    );
    jstring ls_PERM = (jstring)(lJNIEnv->GetStaticObjectField(
        ClassManifestpermission, lid_PERM
    )); 
    return ls_PERM;
}

/**
 * \brief Tests whether a permission is granted.
 * \param[in] app a pointer to the android app.
 * \param[in] perm_name the name of the permission, e.g.,
 *   "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE".
 * \retval true if the permission is granted.
 * \retval false otherwise.
 * \note Requires Android API level 23 (Marshmallow, May 2015)
 */
bool android_has_permission(struct android_app* app, const char* perm_name) {
    JavaVM* lJavaVM = app->activity->vm;
    JNIEnv* lJNIEnv = nullptr; 
    bool lThreadAttached = false;

    // Get JNIEnv from lJavaVM using GetEnv to test whether
    // thread is attached or not to the VM. If not, attach it
    // (and note that it will need to be detached at the end
    //  of the function).
    switch (lJavaVM->GetEnv((void**)&lJNIEnv, JNI_VERSION_1_6)) {
      case JNI_OK:
        break;
      case JNI_EDETACHED: {
        jint lResult = lJavaVM->AttachCurrentThread(&lJNIEnv, nullptr);
        if(lResult == JNI_ERR) {
          throw std::runtime_error("Could not attach current thread");
        }
        lThreadAttached = true;
      } break;
      case JNI_EVERSION:
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid java version");
    }

    bool result = false;

    jstring ls_PERM = android_permission_name(lJNIEnv, perm_name);

    jint PERMISSION_GRANTED = jint(-1);
    {
       jclass ClassPackageManager = lJNIEnv->FindClass(
          "android/content/pm/PackageManager"
       );
       jfieldID lid_PERMISSION_GRANTED = lJNIEnv->GetStaticFieldID(
          ClassPackageManager, "PERMISSION_GRANTED", "I"
       );
       PERMISSION_GRANTED = lJNIEnv->GetStaticIntField(
          ClassPackageManager, lid_PERMISSION_GRANTED
       );
    }
    {
       jobject activity = app->activity->clazz;
       jclass ClassContext = lJNIEnv->FindClass(
          "android/content/Context"
       );
       jmethodID MethodcheckSelfPermission = lJNIEnv->GetMethodID(
          ClassContext, "checkSelfPermission", "(Ljava/lang/String;)I"
       );
       jint int_result = lJNIEnv->CallIntMethod(
           activity, MethodcheckSelfPermission, ls_PERM
       );
       result = (int_result == PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }

    if(lThreadAttached) {
      lJavaVM->DetachCurrentThread();
    }

    return result;
}

/**
 * \brief Query file permissions.
 * \details This opens the system dialog that lets the user
 *  grant (or deny) the permission.
 * \param[in] app a pointer to the android app.
 * \note Requires Android API level 23 (Marshmallow, May 2015)
 */
void android_request_file_permissions(struct android_app* app) {
    JavaVM* lJavaVM = app->activity->vm;
    JNIEnv* lJNIEnv = nullptr; 
    bool lThreadAttached = false;

    // Get JNIEnv from lJavaVM using GetEnv to test whether
    // thread is attached or not to the VM. If not, attach it
    // (and note that it will need to be detached at the end
    //  of the function).
    switch (lJavaVM->GetEnv((void**)&lJNIEnv, JNI_VERSION_1_6)) {
      case JNI_OK:
        break;
      case JNI_EDETACHED: {
        jint lResult = lJavaVM->AttachCurrentThread(&lJNIEnv, nullptr);
        if(lResult == JNI_ERR) {
          throw std::runtime_error("Could not attach current thread");
        }
        lThreadAttached = true;
      } break;
      case JNI_EVERSION:
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid java version");
      }

    jobjectArray perm_array = lJNIEnv->NewObjectArray(
      2,
      lJNIEnv->FindClass("java/lang/String"),
      lJNIEnv->NewStringUTF("")
    );

    lJNIEnv->SetObjectArrayElement(
      perm_array, 0,
      android_permission_name(lJNIEnv, "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
    );

    lJNIEnv->SetObjectArrayElement(
      perm_array, 1,
      android_permission_name(lJNIEnv, "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")        
    );

    jobject activity = app->activity->clazz;

    jclass ClassActivity = lJNIEnv->FindClass(
       "android/app/Activity"
    );

    jmethodID MethodrequestPermissions = lJNIEnv->GetMethodID(
       ClassActivity, "requestPermissions", "([Ljava/lang/String;I)V"
    );

    // Last arg (0) is just for the callback (that I do not use)
    lJNIEnv->CallVoidMethod(
       activity, MethodrequestPermissions, perm_array, 0
    );

    if(lThreadAttached) {
       lJavaVM->DetachCurrentThread();
    }
}

void check_android_permissions(struct android_app* app) {
    bool OK = android_has_permission(
       app, "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    ) && android_has_permission(
       app, "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    );
    if(!OK) {
       android_request_file_permissions(app);
    }
}
```